# SWI prolog: is undo on backtracking possible?

Tags: swi-prolog, control-flow

Is it possible to define an `undo` predicate in SWI Prolog similar to the one in Sicstus Prolog? From the Sicstus description:

```
undo(:Goal)
The goal call(Goal) (see section Control) is executed on backtracking. This predicate is useful if the Goal performs some side-effect that must be done on backtracking to undo another side-effect.
```

The SWI predicate `setup_call_cleanup` won't do, because it does the cleanup right away, instead of waiting until backtracking.

Comment: Now I see that the a newer Sicstus release says: "undo/1
Dropped because it was not possible to ensure the correct behavior in all circumstances. Users that know what they are doing can still call the unsupported predicate prolog:undo/1." https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/relnotes.html/Prolog-Language.html

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this to call Goal on backtracking:

```
undo(Goal) :- true.
undo(Goal) :- call(Goal).
```

I don't have access to Sictus.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, thanks! I think it can be improved to: ``` undo(Goal) :- true. undo(Goal) :- call(Goal), !, fail. ``` because we don't want to execute whatever follows the undo(Goal) statement after we backtrack. However, it has the problem that if a cut follows the undo(Goal), then Goal is not executed. I would like a guarantee that it is always executed, regardless of the context.

Comment: Yes, you got the idea ! Did I answer your question ?

Comment: We still don't have a full answer. I have found a hack that works for my particular case, using a combination of backtrackable global variables (b_setvar, b_getvar) and non-backtrackable ones (nb_setvasr, nb_getvar), but it's not a general solution.